# I'm getting Application Error while hosting Django project on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I get the 'Application Error' After the successfully deployed my project. I don't know why plz help me. It's the first time that I'm hosting my project on Heroku I've never done that before.

these are logs details:

```
»   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.59.2.
2022-01-13T19:10:37.632487+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /
2022-01-13T19:10:37.661207+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=9c5a41e9-725b-4b83-8bf9-81c074c9dc03 fwd="103.69.113.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=49ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-13T19:10:38.425281+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-13T19:10:38.425627+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /
2022-01-13T19:10:38.427129+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=f3370395-81fe-4094-83b6-599e92fb48a1 fwd="103.69.113.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-13T19:10:39.113258+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-13T19:10:39.113745+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /
2022-01-13T19:10:39.115496+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=f15ce14d-9758-4dd6-83ec-6cb9f23adf13 fwd="103.69.113.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-13T19:10:41.921449+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-13T19:10:41.921960+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /
2022-01-13T19:10:41.934548+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=b4c7c6da-8cdc-4c83-abf6-ec654b6c4116 fwd="103.69.113.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-13T19:26:17.883688+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-13T19:26:17.883955+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /
2022-01-13T19:26:17.885404+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=915ef507-e5cd-41bd-980c-2d1fd73237bb fwd="103.69.113.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=27ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-13T19:26:20.551449+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-13T19:26:20.551929+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /favicon.ico
2022-01-13T19:26:20.553636+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=6bcf8946-46d3-462c-8c61-151c340ff426 fwd="103.69.113.112" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-13T20:00:17.849626+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2022-01-13T20:00:17.864652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2022-01-13T20:00:19.342901+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-01-13T20:00:19.586713+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-01-14T06:22:21.727728+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2022-01-14T06:22:21.777322+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2022-01-14T06:22:33.498476+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `waitress-serve --port=48750 beautyparlour.wsgi:application`
2022-01-14T06:22:35.317989+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:waitress:Serving on http://0.0.0.0:48750
2022-01-14T06:22:35.406514+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-01-14T06:22:35.874494+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T06:22:35.907576+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /
2022-01-14T06:22:35.914241+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=f2ce5b63-da84-492f-b148-59cc25479eb2 fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=62ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T06:22:38.570698+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T06:22:38.570913+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /favicon.ico
2022-01-14T06:22:38.574667+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=b2a587ca-57e7-44f5-a368-77cba87e704f fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T06:24:37.465123+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T06:24:37.465328+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /
2022-01-14T06:24:37.469938+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=3c871b8e-02d0-48c2-8a44-6d7a3a5e071a fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T06:24:40.442476+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T06:24:40.442838+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /favicon.ico
2022-01-14T06:24:40.448258+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=3c3e9f45-4b4c-4357-8a48-20d1bd89b40f fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T06:27:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user akashrsingh9324@gmail.com
2022-01-14T06:28:39.334270+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 08837be7 by user akashrsingh9324@gmail.com
2022-01-14T06:28:39.334270+00:00 app[api]: Release v10 created by user akashrsingh9324@gmail.com
2022-01-14T06:28:39.587922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2022-01-14T06:28:39.612181+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2022-01-14T06:28:41.272817+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-01-14T06:28:41.497212+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-01-14T06:28:46.505559+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `waitress-serve --port=55244 beautyparlour.wsgi:application`
2022-01-14T06:28:48.184817+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:waitress:Serving on http://0.0.0.0:55244
2022-01-14T06:28:48.485113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-01-14T06:28:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-01-14T06:34:24.011842+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T06:34:24.050762+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /
2022-01-14T06:34:24.051884+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=eed60b8a-6a25-49d9-9410-af53f044f962 fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=79ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T06:34:27.339467+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=4b3fddc6-3f9c-491d-ba7b-002f04789e77 fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T06:34:27.339837+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T06:34:27.340249+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /favicon.ico
2022-01-14T06:34:29.540521+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T06:34:29.540899+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /
2022-01-14T06:34:29.544086+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=c494d8ca-eb24-4534-b9b6-14159882c25f fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T06:34:30.950030+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=232da2c7-ef85-4d50-931d-b685acacee5c fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T06:34:30.950076+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T06:34:30.950573+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /favicon.ico
2022-01-14T06:34:30.979577+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T06:34:30.979984+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /
2022-01-14T06:34:30.982356+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=96eeebc7-e1ea-49c2-af77-60331de1d95d fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T06:34:32.255058+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T06:34:32.255496+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /
2022-01-14T06:34:32.257774+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=e9d7ae28-75db-4617-976c-692d6f9fe009 fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T06:34:33.399654+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T06:34:33.399952+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /
2022-01-14T06:34:33.402131+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=3b77dbac-bd61-4edd-980b-bc46e842356b fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T06:34:34.479521+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T06:34:34.479915+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /
2022-01-14T06:34:34.482231+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=5a50440f-3199-4c92-8569-415679a14575 fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T06:34:35.814431+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T06:34:35.814810+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /favicon.ico
2022-01-14T06:34:35.817307+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=7fb15c05-e7f5-4d6a-85bb-e68c95396816 fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T07:08:01.769052+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2022-01-14T07:08:01.914332+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2022-01-14T07:08:03.076511+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-01-14T07:08:03.297068+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-01-14T07:30:02.576996+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2022-01-14T07:30:02.598118+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2022-01-14T07:30:14.632303+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `waitress-serve --port=32231 beautyparlour.wsgi:application`
2022-01-14T07:30:17.093949+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:waitress:Serving on http://0.0.0.0:32231
2022-01-14T07:30:17.366678+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-01-14T07:30:18.718009+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T07:30:18.809165+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /
2022-01-14T07:30:18.843564+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=96f52809-ec3b-40d0-973c-b3e6b2bdb54d fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=182ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T07:30:20.458933+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:django.security.DisallowedHost:Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'beautyparlour.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
2022-01-14T07:30:20.459242+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /favicon.ico
2022-01-14T07:30:20.464984+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=5581fa0e-3fd2-4d46-a876-b80aa4f8ed6c fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=32ms status=400 bytes=372 protocol=https
2022-01-14T07:31:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user akashrsingh9324@gmail.com
2022-01-14T07:32:12.148610+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 15c7dd58 by user akashrsingh9324@gmail.com
2022-01-14T07:32:12.148610+00:00 app[api]: Release v11 created by user akashrsingh9324@gmail.com
2022-01-14T07:32:12.291855+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2022-01-14T07:32:13.235820+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-01-14T07:32:13.478742+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-01-14T07:32:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-01-14T07:32:33.926420+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=97c52330-1700-4853-b84f-5406a9c2daed fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-14T07:32:35.912964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=e5e31758-7747-4b46-87f6-7ced9f5e48b3 fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-14T07:53:54.485445+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=90b42c32-e8a6-46f8-beea-2e159ebdc898 fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-14T07:53:57.920632+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=beautyparlour.herokuapp.com request_id=098d9701-3391-48e1-8b90-1b13128bca5b fwd="103.252.5.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is my Procfile

```
web:waitress-serve --port=$PORT beautyparlour.wsgi:application
```

I tried to add or remove space after `web:` but it did not work.

setting.py

```
"""
Django settings for beautyparlour project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["beautyparlour.herokuapp.com", "localhost", "127.0.0.1"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
    'dashboard',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'beautyparlour.urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'beautyparlour.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'beautyparlour/static'

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join('BASE_DIR', '/static/')
]

MEDIA_URL = '/services/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share your settings.py? I assume you didn't add `beautyparlour.herokuapp.com` to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Comment: I have already added but still getting errors.